# protoc-gen-go struct xxx covert to map[string]interface{}

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc, grpc-go

The **struct** in the **.pb.go** file generated by **.proto** file has three additional fields and some other things.like this:

[image]

When converting this **struct** to **json**, if one field is empty, the field will not appear in json. Now I know it can be done using **jsonpb.Marshaler**.

```
m := jsonpb.Marshaler{EmitDefaults: true}
```

Now, I coverting **struct** to **map[string]interface{}**, put it in 
 **InfluxDB**. I have to convert struct to map[string]interface{}.The function **NewPoint** needs. like this:
[image]
[image]

[image]

I use **structs.Map(value)** function in go ,The transformed map has three additional fields, and running the program causes errors，like this:

```
{"error":"unable to parse 'txt,severity=1 CurrentValue=\"1002\",MetricAlias=\"CPU\",XXX_sizecache=0i,XXX_unrecognized= 1552551101': missing field value"}
```

When I remove these three fields, the program runs OK.These three fields are automatically generated, and I have a lot of structs.
What should I do?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf generator adds some additional fields with names starting from `XXX` that are intended for optimizations. You can't change this behavior of `protoc-gen-go`.

The problem is in the way you convert `struct` to `map[sting]interface{}`. It's hard to figure out from which package exactly `structs.Map` comes from. Seems like it goes from here: https://github.com/fatih/structs/blob/master/structs.go#L89 - this code uses `reflect` to iterate through all fields of the structure and push them to `map[sting]interface{}`. You just need to write your own slightly modified version of `FillMap` routine that will omit `XXX` fields.